# Postgres SQL multiple outer joins to generate time series

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to generate a series of 48 periods x days into the future, and displaying matching data from a source table (T1) where available, however this just seems to act like an inner join and only displays rows which have a matching results from T1?

```
select
seq.date,
t1.date,
hh.period,
t1.period
From

myTable t1
right outer  join  (select date(date) from generate_series(current_date,current_date + '12 days'::interval ,'1 day'::interval) date)as  seq 
 ON (seq.date= t1.date)
right outer join (select period from generate_series (1,48) period) hh 
ON (hh.period = t1.period)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross join the series and then left join the table

Cellphone...

```
select seq.date, t1.date, hh.period, t1.period From (select date(date) 
from generate_series(current_date,current_date + '12 days'::interval ,'1 day'::interval) date)as seq 
cross join (select period from generate_series (1,48) period) hh
Left join my table
 ON (hh.period = t1.period)
And (seq.date= t1.date)
```